# Database connection

Tags: mysql, database, connection

On table A I got these two fields:

user_level, username

On table B I got these two fields:

username, notes

I would like to use a mysql query to fetch the notes from all usernames where the level_id = 4.
How would the database connection look like to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing about connection here. You need sql query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `A` JOIN `B` USING(`username`) WHERE `user_level` = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT notes FROM B b INNER JOIN A a ON (b.username = a.username) WHERE a. user_level = 4`

Answer (score 0):

`Select username, notes from B
inner join A on a.username=b.username
where user_level=4`